# Mupad 3D graphing issues

Tags: math, mupad

I have been trying to plot two surfaces on a 3D graph using Mupad.
The first is created by the function:

(x-1)^2 / 4 + (y+2)^2 / 9 + (z+1)^2 = 9

The Second surface I have no problems with apart from some scaling issues:

4(x-1)^2 + 4(y+2)^2 = 81

Additionally, I want to find the intersection of the two surfaces.

My problem here is with the first surface as I can't get it to work using any of the 'plot' functions i am familiar with.

can anyone help me please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

first one is not a function, it is an ellipsoid, so isolate z and define the two halves as +/- sqrt(whatever)